# Publish Jar into Azure Artifact using gradle error

Tags: azure, maven, gradle, groovy, azure-devops

What I'm trying to do is to publish a Jar file into the Azure DevOps artifact using Gradle but I got this error massage:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'publish' not found in root project 'Project1'.
- Try:
  Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

and the Build.gradle file is this:

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'maven-publish' 

publishing { 
    publications { 
        myPublication(MavenPublication) { 
            groupId 'soft' 
            artifactId 'crypto-utils' 
            version '5.2.0' 
            artifact 'C:\Users\d\Desktop\Project1\crypto-utils-5.2.0.jar' 
        } 
    } 

    // Repositories *to* which Gradle can publish artifacts 
    repositories { 
        maven { 
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/soft/pm/_packaging/myFeed/maven/v1' 
            credentials { 
                username "myFeed"
                //The Azure DevOps Services build system will use the "SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" to authenticate to Azure DevOps Services feeds 
                password System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") : vstsMavenAccessToken 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 
 
// Repositories *from* which Gradle can download dependencies; it's the same as above in this example
repositories { 
    maven { 
        url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/soft/pm/_packaging/myFeed/maven/v1' 
        credentials { 
            username "myFeed" 
            //The Azure DevOps Services build system will use the "SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" to authenticate to Azure DevOps Services feeds 
            password System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") : vstsMavenAccessToken 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Any help please

Comment: Hi there, please check whether my answer below can help you. :) If not, could you please provide a sample of your pipeline task and your log, so that people have further investigation about this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem may be caused by using gradle in the wrong path. You need to run gradle in the same directory as the `Build.gradle` file.

If you are using Azure DevOps build pipeline, the root directory path of the repository is `$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)`.

Other than that, you can try `gradle clean build` instead of `gradle build`.